# syntax error near if: sql query

Tags: mysql, ios, sql, if-statement

I have used `if` condition on sql `select` query. When I use `if` condition I'm getting a syntax error

```
     select a.QM_ID,a.QM_QCM_ID,a.QM_Question,a.QM_Type,a.QM_Parent_Id,c.AM_Answer, c.AM_Comments 
from question_master a INNER JOIN Assessment_master c 
on (c.AM_QM_ID = a.QM_ID AND c.AM_HNM_ID = '%d' AND AND c.AM_HM_ID = '%d' and c.AM_ASM_Local_Id = '%@') where a.QM_Parent_Id = '0' and a.QM_Status = 'A' and a.QM_QCM_ID = '%@' and a.QM_QRM_Id = '%@' 
case when(AM_Comments is  null) THEN 
union 
select b.QM_ID,b.QM_QCM_ID,b.QM_Question,b.QM_Type,b.QM_Parent_Id,null,null 
from question_master b INNER JOIN Assessment_master d 
on ((d.AM_QM_ID = b.QM_Parent_Id OR d.AM_QM_ID = b.QM_ID) AND d.AM_HNM_ID = '%d' AND d.AM_HM_ID = '%d' and d.AM_ASM_Local_Id = '%@') where b.QM_Parent_Id != '0' and b.QM_Status = 'A' and b.QM_QCM_ID = '%@' and b.QM_QRM_Id = '%@'
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `if` in `select` statement there is no command like `if` for `select statement` in sqLite.
you can use `Case` instead of If.

EXP: `select case when length(a) > 4 then a else '' end as b
from anyTable`

Comment: I didn't understand..Can you answer my question

Comment: In sqLite there is no command like IF,Instead of IF there is an command CASE you can use it.

Comment: first thing tell me are you writing this sql statement for sqlite or for mySql,if it is sqlite then IF wont work,but for mysql it will work

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_syntax.htm use this link for proper syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.QM_ID,a.QM_QCM_ID,a.QM_Question,a.QM_Type,a.QM_Parent_Id,c.AM_Answer, c.AM_Comments 
from question_master a 
     INNER JOIN Assessment_master c 
         on (c.AM_QM_ID = a.QM_ID 
         AND c.AM_HNM_ID LIKE '%d' AND c.AM_HM_ID LIKE '%d' 
         and c.AM_ASM_Local_Id LIKE '%@') 
     where a.QM_Parent_Id = '0'
         and a.QM_Status = 'A' 
         and a.QM_QCM_ID LIKE '%@' 
         and a.QM_QRM_Id LIKE '%@' AND
         AM_Comments is  null 
union 
    select b.QM_ID,b.QM_QCM_ID,b.QM_Question,b.QM_Type,b.QM_Parent_Id,null,null 
    from question_master b 
    INNER JOIN Assessment_master d 
    on ((d.AM_QM_ID = b.QM_Parent_Id OR d.AM_QM_ID = b.QM_ID) 
       AND d.AM_HNM_ID LIKE '%d' 
       AND d.AM_HM_ID LIKE '%d' 
       and d.AM_ASM_Local_Id LIKE '%@') 
     where b.QM_Parent_Id != '0' 
       and b.QM_Status = 'A' 
       and b.QM_QCM_ID LIKE '%@' 
       and b.QM_QRM_Id LIKE '%@'
```

Comment: Your answer taking first query is null. I have to check second union query.